# greedy best first search

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence

What heuristic functions transform greedy best-first search into breadth-first search, depth-first search, and uniform-cost search?

Comment: Add some context? Does the question suite math.stackexchange best?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, you may want to take Lorenzo's advice, as well as taking a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) :) Best of luck in your search

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather sparse on details, and is a little odd since greedy best-first search (GBFS) implies some cost of a path, unlike BFS and DFS.
Sometimes a *distance to goal* estimate is also known.
(Also, the [CS stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate for questions like this, though I think there is reasonable space for overlap).

In any case, GBFS has a heuristic function $h(n)$ for any given node $n$ that determines the order in which they are checked/queued. $h$ controls the order of insertion into the (priority) queue to check, in other words.
Lets start at node $s$.

For BFS, $h(n)$ should be less based on the depth of the search tree from $s$. More precisely, when you process a node $n$, all its children should be added to the queue with priority $h(n)+1$.

For DFS, it's the opposite. Add the children, but assign $h(n)-1$ instead. As you get deeper, the latest seen nodes will have the highest priority.

For uniform cost search, we are essentially trying to do [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for a single goal node. Assuming an edge-weighted graph, use the same heuristic as BFS, except add the edge weight instead of $1$.